# How to allow ICMPv6 on Oracle Cloud?

Tags: oracle, cloud, ping, ipv6, icmp

I have allowed ICMP on IPv6 for my VPS in Oracle Cloud but still it dosen't work. I can access the internet through IPv6 also other incoming traffic such as http/https through IPv6 works. But I cannot figure out to get ICMP working through IPv6 without allowing all traffic through IPv6.
PS: I have opened all ports through my Ubuntu iptables too.
Here's the rule scrrenshot-[ICMPv6 rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4y25.png)

Comment: ICMP does not use ports because IP does not have ports (ICMP is an integral part of IP). Ports are addresses for _some_ transport protocols, but not either IP version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is connected with difference between IPv4 ICMP and IPv6 ICMP. To correctly set-up the rule, you need to use IPv6-ICMP IP protocol instead of typical ICMP (which is IPv4 only). Correct rule set-up is on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHtBd.jpg).